# Lista de Links Primefaces

Tags: java, spring, primefaces

tengo un problema con una Datatable.
Primero la data table genera los datos de los primeros 10 registros sin pasar parámetros, en cada registro se tiene una columna con varios links de Acciones como Editar, Eliminar, y ver su histórico. 
También se tienen opciones para que el usuario pueda generar una consulta con distintos parámetros como Fechas, Número de serie, etc.
El problema está en los Links de acciones, cuando se cargan los datos por primera vez, los links funcionan muy bien, pero cuando se genera una consulta con parámetros del usuario, los links pasan un parámetro distinto al que se está seleccionando, por ejemplo selecciono el registro 10 y me manda a Editar el registro 15.

Estoy usando Primefaces 6.0, acá está el JSF:

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="WEB-INF/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="head">
        <style type="text/css">
            .grid-pad .ui-panelgrid-content .ui-panelgrid-cell.ui-grid-col-12 {
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </ui:define>
 <ui:define name="content">
  <div class="ui-g">
   <div class="ui-g-12">
    <div class="card centerText">
     <h1 class="lightBlack">CONSULTA DE RESGUARDOS</h1>
     <p class="lightBlack"></p>

     <h:form>
     <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
     <input type="hidden" name="nombreUserLog" id="nombreUserLog" value="#{loginMB.nombre}" />
     <h:panelGrid columns="4" layout="grid" style="width: 100%" cellpadding="10">
      <p:outputLabel>Número de Serie</p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel>Fecha Inicial</p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel>Fecha Final</p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel></p:outputLabel>
      
      <p:inputText id="numSerie" value="#{resguardoMB.numSerie}"></p:inputText>
      <p:calendar id="fechaAsignInicio" value="#{resguardoMB.fechaAsignInicio}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true" />
      <p:calendar id="fechaAsignFinal" value="#{resguardoMB.fechaAsignFinal}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true" />
      <p:button rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq ('SUPERADMIN' or 'ADMIN')}" value="Nuevo Resguardo" outcome="createResguardo"></p:button>
      
      <p:outputLabel>Nombre de Staff</p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel>Tipo de Resguardo</p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel></p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel></p:outputLabel>
      
      <p:selectOneMenu id="userAsign" value="#{resguardoMB.userAsign}">
       <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="-- Seleccione --" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{usersMB.usersList}" var="userasign" itemValue="#{userasign.nombre}" itemLabel="#{userasign.nombre}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoResguardo" value="#{resguardoMB.tipoResguardo}">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Seleccione --" itemValue=""/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Usuario" itemValue="Usuario"/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="TI" itemValue="TI"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <p:commandButton value="Buscar"  update="@form" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
      <p:outputLabel></p:outputLabel>
      
     </h:panelGrid>
     
     <p:separator/>
     
      <p:dataTable tableStyle = "table-layout: auto;" id="Resguardos" var="resguardo"
       value="#{resguardoMB.resguardoList}" style="width: 100%">
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="#" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.idResguardo}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Número de Serie" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.numSerie}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Nombre del Staff" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.userAsign}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Tipo Resguardo" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.tipoResguardo}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="País" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.paisUserAsign}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Estado" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.descEstado}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Fecha de Asignación" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.fechaAsignacion}"> 
         <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"></f:convertDateTime>
        </h:outputText>
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Acciones" />
        </f:facet>
        
        <p:commandLink action="#{resguardoMB.consultaResguardo(resguardo.idResguardo)}">
         <h:outputText value="Ver "/>
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:outputLabel rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN' or (loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'ADMIN' and resguardo.descEstado eq 'Activo')}">-</p:outputLabel>
        <p:commandLink rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN' or (loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'ADMIN' and resguardo.descEstado eq 'Activo')}" action="#{resguardoMB.getResguardoByID(resguardo.idResguardo)}" ajax="false">
         <h:outputText value=" Editar " />
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:outputLabel rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN'}">-</p:outputLabel>
        <p:commandLink rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN'}" action="#{resguardoMB.deleteResguardo(resguardo.idResguardo)}" update="@form">
         <h:outputText value=" Archivar " />
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:outputLabel rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN' or rol eq 'ADMIN'}">-</p:outputLabel>
        <p:commandLink rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN' or rol eq 'ADMIN'}" action="#{resguardohistMB.getResguardohistList(resguardo.idResguardo)}" >
         <h:outputText value=" Histórico " />
        </p:commandLink>
       </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>
     </h:form>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Este es el método que se llama para llenar la datatable:

```
public List<Resguardo> getResguardoList() {

    if (null == getNumSerie() && null == getFechaAsignInicio() && null == getFechaAsignFinal()
            && null == getUserAsign() && null == getTipoResguardo()) {
        resguardoList = new ArrayList<Resguardo>();
        resguardoList.addAll(getResguardoService().getAllResguardos());
    } else {
        if (null != getNumSerie() & !"".equals(getNumSerie())) {
            resguardoList = new ArrayList<Resguardo>();
            resguardoList.addAll(getResguardoService().getResguardoListByNumSerie(getNumSerie()));
            setNumSerie("");
        } else if (null != getUserAsign() & !"".equals(getUserAsign())) {
            resguardoList = new ArrayList<Resguardo>();
            resguardoList.addAll(getResguardoService().getResguardoListByUserAsign(getUserAsign()));
            setUserAsign("");
        } else if (null != getTipoResguardo() & !"".equals(getTipoResguardo())) {
            resguardoList = new ArrayList<Resguardo>();
            resguardoList.addAll(getResguardoService().getResguardoListByTipoResg(getTipoResguardo()));
            setTipoResguardo("");
        } else if ((null != getFechaAsignInicio() & !"".equals(getFechaAsignInicio()))
                && (null != getFechaAsignFinal() & !"".equals(getFechaAsignFinal()))) {
            resguardoList = new ArrayList<Resguardo>();
            resguardoList.addAll(getResguardoService().getResguardoListByFechas(sdf.format(getFechaAsignInicio()),
                    sdf.format(getFechaAsignFinal())));
            setFechaAsignInicio(null);
            setFechaAsignFinal(null);
        }
    }
    for(Resguardo resg : resguardoList){
        if(resg.getIndEstado() == '1'){
            resg.setDescEstado("Activo");
        }else{
            resg.setDescEstado("Archivado");
        }
    }

    setIdResguardo(0);

    return resguardoList;
}
```

Este es el método que se llama para el histórico, como lo comentaba cuando se carga la lista sin parámetros, se muestra el registro correcto al pulsar el link, cuando se pide la consulta con parámetros se muestra mal el registro:

```
public String getResguardohistList(int idResguardo){

    log.info("Obteniendo ID");
    log.info(idResguardo);

    resguardoHistList = new ArrayList<Resguardohist>();
    resguardoHistList.addAll(getResguardohistService().getByIdResguardo(idResguardo));

    for(Resguardohist resg : resguardoHistList){
        if(resg.getIndEstado() == '1'){
            resg.setDescEstado("Activo");
        }else{
            resg.setDescEstado("Archivado");
        }
    }

    return "historicoResguardo";

}
```

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar le agradecería mucho.

Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

Ya he conseguido la respuesta en este post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-selected-row-to-commandlink-inside-datatable-or-uirepeat

Usando la primera opción, mi código quedó así

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="WEB-INF/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="head">
        <style type="text/css">
            .grid-pad .ui-panelgrid-content .ui-panelgrid-cell.ui-grid-col-12 {
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </ui:define>
 <ui:define name="content">
  <div class="ui-g">
   <div class="ui-g-12">
    <div class="card centerText">
     <h1 class="lightBlack">CONSULTA DE RESGUARDOS</h1>
     <p class="lightBlack"></p>

     <h:form>
     <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
     <input type="hidden" name="nombreUserLog" id="nombreUserLog" value="#{loginMB.nombre}" />
     <h:panelGrid columns="4" layout="grid" style="width: 100%" cellpadding="10">
      <p:outputLabel>Número de Serie</p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel>Fecha Inicial</p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel>Fecha Final</p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel></p:outputLabel>
      
      <p:inputText id="numSerie" value="#{resguardoMB.numSerie}"></p:inputText>
      <p:calendar id="fechaAsignInicio" value="#{resguardoMB.fechaAsignInicio}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true" />
      <p:calendar id="fechaAsignFinal" value="#{resguardoMB.fechaAsignFinal}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true" />
      <p:button rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq ('SUPERADMIN' or 'ADMIN')}" value="Nuevo Resguardo" outcome="createResguardo"></p:button>
      
      <p:outputLabel>Nombre de Staff</p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel>Tipo de Resguardo</p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel></p:outputLabel>
      <p:outputLabel></p:outputLabel>
      
      <p:selectOneMenu id="userAsign" value="#{resguardoMB.userAsign}">
       <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="-- Seleccione --" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{usersMB.usersList}" var="userasign" itemValue="#{userasign.nombre}" itemLabel="#{userasign.nombre}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoResguardo" value="#{resguardoMB.tipoResguardo}">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Seleccione --" itemValue=""/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Usuario" itemValue="Usuario"/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="TI" itemValue="TI"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <p:commandButton value="Buscar"  update="@form" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
      <p:outputLabel></p:outputLabel>
      
     </h:panelGrid>
     
     <p:separator/>
     
      <p:dataTable tableStyle = "table-layout: auto;" id="Resguardos" var="resguardo"
       value="#{resguardoMB.resguardoList}" style="width: 100%">
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="#" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.idResguardo}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Número de Serie" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.numSerie}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Nombre del Staff" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.userAsign}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Tipo Resguardo" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.tipoResguardo}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="País" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.paisUserAsign}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Estado" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.descEstado}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Fecha de Asignación" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{resguardo.fechaAsignacion}"> 
         <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"></f:convertDateTime>
        </h:outputText>
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Acciones" />
        </f:facet>
        
        <p:commandLink action="#{resguardoMB.consultaResguardo}">
         <f:param name="idResguardo" value="#{resguardo.idResguardo}" />
         <h:outputText value="Ver "/>
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:outputLabel rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN' or (loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'ADMIN' and resguardo.descEstado eq 'Activo')}">-</p:outputLabel>
        <p:commandLink rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN' or (loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'ADMIN' and resguardo.descEstado eq 'Activo')}" action="#{resguardoMB.getResguardoByID}" ajax="false">
         <f:param name="idResguardo" value="#{resguardo.idResguardo}" />
         <h:outputText value=" Editar " />
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:outputLabel rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN'}">-</p:outputLabel>
        <p:commandLink rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN'}" action="#{resguardoMB.deleteResguardo}" update="@form">
         <f:param name="idResguardo" value="#{resguardo.idResguardo}" />
         <h:outputText value=" Archivar " />
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:outputLabel rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN' or rol eq 'ADMIN'}">-</p:outputLabel>
        <p:commandLink rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq 'SUPERADMIN' or rol eq 'ADMIN'}" action="#{resguardohistMB.getResguardohistList}" >
         <f:param name="idResguardo" value="#{resguardo.idResguardo}" />
         <h:outputText value=" Histórico " />
        </p:commandLink>
       </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>
     </h:form>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

En mi Bean, tomé el parámetro así:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.idResguardo}")
private int idResguardo;
```

Igual muchas gracias a todos